# Can i be reject my app with a one warning to upload to iOS appstore?

Tags: ios, upload, app-store

I have a one warning about Flite Text To Speech in my iOS project.

Is there any problem with it to upload my app to App Store?

Can i be reject from Review?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically a warning isn't enough to get your app rejected. They will review your app and put it through its paces. If that warning leads to crashes or usability issues, you would likely get rejected for those instead.

It is generally a good rule to ship your app free of warnings, but it is by no means a requirement.

Comment: thanks you for your answers.That warning can't make my app to crash.

Comment: Sometimes warnings can't be helped. Good that you at least care about them enough to ask. Good luck in review.